# AIX auto completion:  how to show a whole file name by type in only a few letters

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I used to work on Redhat Linux and really enjoy its feature that I can only type a few letters on the command line, and the rest of a file name would show up.  I am running AIX 5 or 6 now, and it does not have this feature.

Do you know if there is a way to turn on this feature in AIX?  Does AIX have this feature at all?

Thanks so much.

Dave

Comment: Do you mean auto-completion?  What shell are you using?  This is probably better asked on SuperUser.com

Comment: Yes. I mean auto completion. It is a Korn shell.

Comment: The [unix stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) might also be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81022/how-to-autocomplete-at-the-korn-shell-command-line-with-the-vi-editor  or just switch to bash.

Comment: You could compile `bash` or `zsh` on your AIX machine, and use it as your login shell (probably changing that shell with `chsh`)

Answer (score 1):

AIX does have this feature.

By default, AIX uses korn shell and vi as the editor. Command completion is:

ESC+\

To scroll through command history use:
ESC+k
ESC+j

vi is tricky to use at first, but it puts a whole new spin on the keyboard once you get common functionality down.